# Tomcat 5.5 https configuration in Windows Server 2008 64bit

Tags: java, tomcat, https, tomcat5.5

I have configured `server.xml` file as below for accessing my site using https.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <!-- Comment these entries out to disable JMX MBeans support used for the 
       administration web application -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" SSLRandomSeed="builtin"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.ServerLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreConfigLifecycleListener"/>

  <!-- Global JNDI resources -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>

    <!-- Test entry for demonstration purposes -->
    <Environment name="simpleValue" type="java.lang.Integer" value="30"/>

    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
       description="User database that can be updated and saved"
           factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />

  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- Define the Tomcat Stand-Alone Service -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned.  Each Connector passes requests on to the
         associated "Container" (normally an Engine) for processing.

         By default, a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector is established on port 8080.
         You can also enable an SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 by
         following the instructions below and uncommenting the second Connector
         entry.  SSL support requires the following steps (see the SSL Config
         HOWTO in the Tomcat 5 documentation bundle for more detailed
         instructions):
         * If your JDK version 1.3 or prior, download and install JSSE 1.0.2 or
           later, and put the JAR files into "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext".
         * Execute:
             %JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA (Windows)
             $JAVA_HOME/bin/keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA  (Unix)
           with a password value of "changeit" for both the certificate and
           the keystore itself.

         By default, DNS lookups are enabled when a web application calls
         request.getRemoteHost().  This can have an adverse impact on
         performance, so you can disable it by setting the
         "enableLookups" attribute to "false".  When DNS lookups are disabled,
         request.getRemoteHost() will return the String version of the
         IP address of the remote client.
    -->

    <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
    <Connector
port="8000"               maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443 -->

      <Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                 maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
                 enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
                 acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
                 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
                 keystoreFile="D:\Tomcat5\conf\mykey.keystore" keystorePass="mykey123"
               />

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" 
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />


    <!-- Define the top level container in our container hierarchy -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

    <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
           resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
           that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
           available for use by the Realm.  -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
             resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

      <!-- Define the default virtual host
           Note: XML Schema validation will not work with Xerces 2.2.
       -->
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
       unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
       xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

after configuration when i access tomcat manager using `http://localhost:8443` i am able to access tomcat manager but when i try using  `https://localhost:8443` unable to access tomcat manager.

also unable to access my site using this url : `https://localhost:8443/mysite`

why i am unable to access my site using **https**? is there anything wrong in server.xml file?
is there anything that i need to configure in server?or is there any server settings?

I am also accessing web sites running on IIS from my server machine..

Comment: What does the error log show you?  Did you actually create the keystore file `D:\Tomcat5\conf\mykey.keystore`?  Does this file even exist?

Comment: yes. I have created .keystore file and put that in conf folder. Catalina didnt show any error.

Comment: Backslashes have bitten me so often that I totally eliminate them from any java code, except for their original java use: Escape codes. Replace the backslash with a forward slash in your file path and try again - report back. I can't count the number of times when "\tomcat" resolved to "<TAB>omcat".

Comment: If you can access port 8443 via HTTP there is something wrong already. You're decades out of date with Tomcat 5.5, but there is a Connector attribute that tells it to use TLS, and you clearly haven't specified it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem as you have described. 
i have resolved it by changing connector in `server.xml` file as below.

```
  <Connector SSLEnabled="true" acceptCount="100" clientAuth="false"
    disableUploadTimeout="true" enableLookups="false" maxThreads="25"
    port="8443" keystoreFile="D:/Tomcat5/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="password"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" scheme="https"
    secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

Please don't forget to replace your keystore file path and password in connector.

Finally restart tomcat and check.